# Why Won't Swift 2 Read this iOS File?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to read/write some JSON data using a file in my Documents directory. I write the file using:

```
func WriteJSonToFile(fileName : String, buffer : String) -> Bool
{
    let filePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        try buffer.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        return true
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return false
}
```

This works fine and I can open the file in a text editor.  Then I turn around and try to read it with:

```
func ReadJSonFromFile(fileName : String) ->String
{
    let filePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        let databuffer = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return databuffer
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return ""
}
```

On the read, I always receive the error:

```
The file “authdata.dat” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8).
```

But, I *wrote* the file using Unicode (UTF-8) so why can't I *read* the file using the exact same encoding?  This strikes me as very odd. Can anyone offer insight or a work-around?  Thank you!

Comment: I cannot see an obvious error, and `WriteJSonToFile("file.txt", buffer: "Hello World"); let x = ReadJSonFromFile("file.txt"); print(x)` works without problems using your functions. Did you triple-check that the same file name is used for both reading and writing?

Comment: arrgghhh...I using a different extension when reading. That file existed because of an earlier experiment so I didn't get a "not found" error. THANK YOU - I should give you the "answer" tag.

Comment: I am glad that you solved your problem. I have voted to close the question as off-topic ("A problem that can no longer be reproduced") however, as I don't think that it is useful for future readers.

Comment: I thought about deleting it altogether - it *is* kind of embarrassing. But, you never know, someone may have the same problem and find it useful to take your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
var readError:NSError?

if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!, options:NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error:&readError) {
    let stringData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("data read: \(stringData)")
}
```

As a side note - why don't you save your file with extension `.json` instead of `.dat`.

Comment: Thanks but it turned out to be a file name difference as Martin suggested.

Comment: It does not make any difference if you read the file into NSData first or directly into a string.